# Como retornar uma mensagem "'Nenhum tipo de documento cadastrado", quando não retornar nada do banco

Tags: html, html5, front-end, thymeleaf

Gostaria de saber como eu coloco no thymeleaf para quando não encontrar nada no banco eu retorno uma mensagem personalizada na página web "Nenhum tipo de documento cadastrado".

Tipo Documento



    
        Tipos de Documentos
         Adicionar

```
<div class="container-fluid px-5">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>         
            <tr>
                <th >Descrição</th>
                <th >Opções</th>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr th:each="tipoDocumento: ${tipoDocumentos}">
          <td th:text="${tipoDocumento.descricao}"> </td>
          <td> 
                        <a class="btn btn-primary-link btn-onlyicon py-2" th:href="@{'/selecao/tipo-documento/editar/' + ${tipoDocumento.id}}" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary-link btn-onlyicon py-2" th:href="@{'/selecao/tipo-documento/remover/' + ${tipoDocumento.id}}"  title="Remover" onclick="confirm({},event)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </td>
          </tr>    
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Provavelmente o retorno do banco vai ser Vazio, Você pode Colocar essa mensagem de Erro dentro dessa descrição no back-end ou Criar alguma rotina em javascript, com um alert por exemplo, quando a descrição for vazia, e ai o usuário vai ser avisado que nenhum tipo de Documento foi Cadastrado. :)

Comment: Recomendo colocar um return no back-end com uma mensagem e quando clicar no link e retornar essa mensagem você dispara um Alert!